# How to send email with a designated sender name(the sender) in Gmail API? (Go)

Tags: gmail-api

I write the message to send as below, but it doesn't show MyName when it is received by the receiver.

```
message := []byte("From: MyName <xxx@xyz.com>\r\n" +
        "To:yyy@xyz.com\r\n" +
        "Subject: Please confirm your email address.\r\n")
```

Comment: Are you using a random name in the `From`-header, or is it an actual [alias](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en)?

Answer (score 0):

@Clerk  Here is the a related SO question that will help you format your [sender email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11212257/java-mail-senders-address-displayed-rather-than-his-name)

Here is a sample code from the document:

```
/**
* Create a MimeMessage using the parameters provided.
*
* @param to Email address of the receiver.
* @param from Email address of the sender, the mailbox account.
* @param subject Subject of the email.
* @param bodyText Body text of the email.
* @return MimeMessage to be used to send email.
* @throws MessagingException
*/
 public static MimeMessage createEmail(String to, String from, String subject,
String bodyText) throws MessagingException {
Properties props = new Properties();
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
MimeMessage email = new MimeMessage(session);
InternetAddress tAddress = new InternetAddress(to);
InternetAddress fAddress = new InternetAddress(from);
email.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
email.addRecipient(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO,
new InternetAddress(to));
email.setSubject(subject);
email.setText(bodyText);
return email;
 }
```

The next step is to encode the MimeMessage, instantiate a Message object, and set the base64url encoded message string as the value of the raw proper

```
/**
* Create a Message from an email
*
* @param email Email to be set to raw of message
* @return Message containing base64url encoded email.
* @throws IOException
* @throws MessagingException
*/
 public static Message createMessageWithEmail(MimeMessage email)
 throws MessagingException, IOException {
 ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 email.writeTo(bytes);
 String encodedEmail = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(bytes.toByteArray());
 Message message = new Message();
 message.setRaw(encodedEmail);
 return message;
}
```